# Unpack NumPy array by column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, argument-unpacking

If I have a NumPy array, for example 5x3, is there a way to unpack it column by column all at once to pass to a function rather than like this: `my_func(arr[:, 0], arr[:, 1], arr[:, 2])`?

Kind of like `*args` for list unpacking but by column.

Comment: `np.hsplit(x,x.shape[1])`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can unpack the transpose of the array in order to use the columns for your function arguments:

```
my_func(*arr.T)
```

Here's a simple example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
array([[ 0,  5, 10],
       [ 1,  6, 11],
       [ 2,  7, 12],
       [ 3,  8, 13],
       [ 4,  9, 14]])
```

Let's write a function to add the columns together (normally done with `x.sum(axis=1)` in NumPy):

```
def add_cols(a, b, c):
    return a+b+c
```

Then we have:

```
>>> add_cols(*x.T)
array([15, 18, 21, 24, 27])
```

NumPy arrays will be unpacked along the first dimension, hence the need to transpose the array.

Answer (score 16):

[numpy.split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) splits an array into multiple sub-arrays. In your case, `indices_or_sections` is 3 since you have 3 columns, and `axis = 1` since we're splitting by column.

```
my_func(numpy.split(array, 3, 1))
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess `numpy.split` will not suffice in the future. Instead, it should be

```
my_func(tuple(numpy.split(array, 3, 1)))
```

Currently, python prints the following warning:

> FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional
>   indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`.
>   In the future this will be interpreted as an array index,
>   `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a
>   different result.

Comment: This gave me the answer I needed: wrap the numpy array in a `tuple()`.