# How to shift entire groups in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given the following data:

```
data = {'a' : [1,1,1,8,8,3,3,3,3,4,4] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would now like to shift the whole thing down by n *groups*, so that their current order is preserved. The desired output for a shift of n=1 would be:

```
desired_output = {'a': [NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,8,8,8,8,3,3] }
desired_output_df = pd.DataFrame(desired_output)
```

a shift of n=2 should be:

```
desired_output = {'a': [NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,1,1,1,1,8,8] }
desired_output_df = pd.DataFrame(desired_output)
```

I have been messing around with groupby/transform/apply but haven't gotten anything to work so far. If I groupby and then shift, it shifts each group giving the output of:

```
NOT_desired_output = {'a' : [NaN, 1, 1, NaN, 8, NaN, 3,3,3, NaN, 4]}
```

I could brute force it by iterating, but I'm sure there's a better solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting operation. I can think of an alternative way to do it with `replace`.

To shift by 1 group:

```
>>> df['b'] = df.a.shift()
>>> x = df[df.a != df.b]
>>> df.replace(*x.values.T)
```

Which gives the DataFrame:

```
     a   b
0  NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN
2  NaN NaN
3    1 NaN
4    1   1
5    8   1
6    8   8
7    8   8
8    8   8
9    3   8
10   3   3
```

And we just want column `a` of this DataFrame:

```
desired_output_df = pd.DataFrame(_, columns=['a'])
```

To shift by more than one group, you just need to shift column `b` of `x`. If you want to shift by `n` groups, you need to shift `x.b` an additional `n-1` times. Just insert the line

```
>>> x.b = x.b.shift(n-1)
```

after `x = df[df.a != df.b]` and then perform the `df.replace(*x.values.T)` step.

Comment: Interesting-- I'm trying to see if this works for shifting more than once and updating the question to include that

Comment: ah great- i'm still trying to understand exactly how it works, but it clearly does work!

Comment: `(*x.values.T)` is tuple unpacking of a NumPy array by column (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27047043/3923281) answer for an explanation). It essentially uses columns `a` and `b` for the appropriate find/replace lists.