# How to shift entire group of multiple columns

Tags: pandas, group-by, shift

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(22)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': np.random.rand(200), 'b': np.random.rand(200), 'x': np.tile(np.concatenate([np.repeat('F', 5), np.repeat('G', 5)]), 20)})
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1, 2], list(range(0, 10)), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
df.index.names = ['g_id', 'm_id', 'object_id']
```

I'd like to shift the values for the entire groups defined by `['g_id', 'm_id']` so that for example:

- the value of `['a', 'b']` columns in index `(1, 1, 1)` of the new data frame would be the value from index `(1, 0, 1)` of the original dataframe, i.e. `[0.208461, 0.980866]`
- the value of `['a', 'b']` columns in index `(2, 4, 3)` of the new data frame would be the value from index `(2, 3, 3)` of the original data frame, i.e. `[0.651138, 0.559126]`.

The operation is similar to the one covered in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305135/how-to-shift-entire-groups-in-pandas-groupby). However, I need to do this with multiple columns and I had no luck trying to generalise the provided solution.

Comment: What is supposed to appear in the first row of the new dataframe?

Comment: 0 at best, but if it will be `NaN` then I suppose I could easily fill it with `.fillna`. Actually, the value would be missing for not only first row, but all ten referring to `m_id == 0`

Comment: this might sound lazy, but could you convert the columns you want to shift to a dict, pop out the rows you want to move up or down by, use the result to recreate a df, reset the index, and use concatenate with the original datafame?