# Compact form of python first and second elements of array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have defined two arrays:

```
a=np.array([[2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]])
b=np.array([-1,-2])
```

and created a third one:

```
x=np.asarray([[x - a/2, x + a/2] for x in b])
```

Now, I have defined two variables

```
u,v = x[:,0], x[:,1]
```

My question is extremely simple: is there a way to define those variables without the comma, using *only* array operations? If I write

```
 u,v = x[:,]
```

the ordering comes out wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for `u, v = x.T`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack NumPy array by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046533/unpack-numpy-array-by-column)

Comment: Not really. I want exactly the ``u`` and ``v`` that come from ``u,v = x[:,0], x[:,1]``, but was wondering if there's no way to write this compactly.

Comment: I know this is possible with ``u,v = np.hsplit(x,x.shape[1])`` or just a ``for`` loop, but it's weird that there's no manipulation of ``:`` and ``,`` that doesn't do this.

Comment: If I run this correctly in my head, `x` is (2,2,3,3) shape. `u` is (2,3,3), selecting on axis 1. `x[:,]` is just `x`. Unpacking just iterates on first axis.  You'd have to swap axes to unpack on the 2nd - i.e. move 2nd to 1st.

Comment: Unpacking is a basic Python operation, essentially iterating on the object - such as a tuple or list.   Simple iteration on an array is along the first, outermost, axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x is 2D:

```
u, v = x.T
```

If x is ND:

```
u, v = np.swapaxes(x, 0, 1)
```

To confirm:

```
>>> np.all(u == x[:, 0])
True

>>> np.all(v == x[:, 1])
True
```

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, but ``swapaxes`` worked.